# How to fix the mask on the device screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

Now. There are two buttons. If I click one button, the `#mask` will show.

My target is to show this web on the mobile phone.
To tell you the truth, I need to tap one Image which inside in the mobile view,  then the Image will change its size and show at the above of the mobile view.(above means set => index: 99999);

This is my code.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>textFixCover</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <link href="css/mui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="fonts/iconfont.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        html {
            background-color: #fff;
            height: 2000px;
            position: relative;
        }                   
        #mask {
            position: fix;
            top: 20px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;       
            height: 600px;  
            display: none;
            background-color: greenyellow;
            z-index: 99999; 
        }           
        #mask .mui-slider {
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            height: 400px;
        }           
        #bottom-btn {
            margin-top: 1400px;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #4CD964;          
        }           
        #top-btn {
            margin-top: 400px;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #FF5053;
        }           
    </style>
</head>
<body>      
     <section id="top-btn"></section>        
     <select id="mask"> </select>       
     <section id="bottom-btn"></section>         
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#top-btn').click(function(){
            $('#mask').css('display','block');              
            setTimeout(function(){
            $('#mask').css('display','none');                
            },3000);
        });         
        $('#bottom-btn').click(function(){
            $('#mask').css('display','block');
                setTimeout(function(){
                $('#mask').css('display','none');
            },3000);
        });
     </script>
</body>
```

Now I face a problem. If I click the `bottom-btn`, how to set the mask on the current screen. Set it position on the top of the device window. In other words, I mean to fix the mask on the device screen, ignore the web view scroll.

My aim is when I click the `bottom btn`, I will see the mask on the device screen.
I don't need to scroll the web view.

I debug the code on the chrome console to simulate mobile devices

This is the perfect result. 
[image]

Comment: Use 5vh instead of 20px for the top position of #mask 5vh is relative to the viewport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some time to understand what your problem was and i didn't get it until i tested the code myself. There is a slight mistake in the code, you need to set the `position` element of `#mask` to `position: fixed` rather than, `position: fix`. 'Fix' is not a value. Once i changed it to fixed, it was working as i think you wish it to work.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to do this:

```
#mask {background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);}
```